# Static speaker noise when booting

Tags: boot, sound, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my HP ZBook Studio G3.
When booting, there is a loud static noise from my speakers somewhere where the bios logo shows, which then gets muted. A very brief noise is also played just before the login screen of Ubuntu.

After that, the usual drum sound plays and everything is fine. No noise, audio is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for me as well with my HP ZBook Studio G3 and I am on Windows 10. Usually it is a static hiss, but today it was a loud beeping noise.

Guess it is something with the startup and not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to do the BIOS update despite many attempts, but since I don't use the internal speakers for anything, I got rid of the hiss by disabling the internal speakers from BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I also used to have the same problem, first with Windows 7 then Windows 10. A BIOS upgrade took care of it.

You can download the BIOS update from here:

[HP Drivers & Software](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=8934841&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4192)

I am using version 01.14 Rev.A (12 Sep 2016)

The upgrade is a simple Windows application, it will do several reboots. It takes A WHILE (I don't remember exactly how long, but it was a lot more than I expected with no notification of any progress), so don't panic and let it do its thing for as long as it's needed.